# Contact info for a professor's letter of recommendation

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, recommendation-letter, email

Is it okay if the applicant provides a professor's official email and the professor uploads the letter of recommendation (LOR) from the same official email, but mistakenly mentions their personal email instead of their official email on the letter of recommendation as their contact details?

Comment: This is too variable to answer. Every university will be different. Ask the university or the department. The US has no uniform system for any such thing.

Comment: It might be helpful if you explain why this is an issue: using the official email everywhere seems like it makes more sense than mixing them. Can you clarify?

Comment: @AzorAhai your point looks obvious to me. I mean it’s like you subscribe in a website with your Gmail or Yahoo email but you expect to login with your .edu email! But a lot of LoR systems specifically in the US clearly states that the recommender should hold an academic status and have a valid academic email address .

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Which is why I was confused by your comment about a professor using their gmail or yahoo email in *their* contact details.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I list both my gmail and my current university email on a lot of my things. This is because I've had positions at a bunch of different schools and haven't landed a permanent position yet. This makes it easier for people to a hold of me if/when my position again changes.

Comment: I edited again. In English, it's okay to just say "email," "email-id" is redundant and a bit confusing for me, at least.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is okay for a professor to have alternative contact information on their letter of recommendation. If you are a student worried about this, you need not worry further.